# Mysterious transaction fault when trying to dumpdata

Tags: django, export, psycopg2

I'm trying to dump a Django app's models as a fixture. When I run the command:

```
 ./manage.py dumpdata core
```

(where `core` is the name of my app), I get

```
Error: Unable to serialize database: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

When I run it with `--verbosity=2` I get no extra info. If I run it with `--traceback` the stack trace is predictable.

If I try doing this for each of my models individually, it all works fine.

How do I start debugging this?

Running Django==1.3, psycopg2==2.2.2

Answer (score 0):

I got this when I changed one of my models slightly and then did a dumpdata.  You may want to try a syncdb first, or running the server and making sure everything works.